# THREE.Sprite size in px with sizeAttenuation false

Tags: three.js, sprite

I'm trying to scale sprites to have size defined in px. regardless of camera FOV and so on. I have sizeAttenuation set to false, as I dont want them to be scaled based on distance from camera, but I struggle with setting the scale. Dont really know the conversion formula and when I hardcoded the scale with some number that's ok on one device, on the other its wrong. Any advice or help how to have the sprites with the correct sizing accross multiple devices? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Corrected answer:**

Sprite size is measured in world units. Converting world units to pixel units may take a lot of calculations because it varies based on your camera's FOV, distance from camera, window height, pixel density, and so on...

To use pixel-based units, I recommend switching from `THREE.Sprite` to [`THREE.Points`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Points). It's material `THREE.PointsMaterial` has a [size property](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/PointsMaterial.size) that's measured in pixels if `sizeAttenuation` is set to `false`. Just keep in mind that it has a max size limitation based on the device's hardware, defined by gl.ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE.

**My original answer continues below**:

However, "1 px" is a subjective measurement nowadays because if you use `renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);` then you'll get different sprite sizes on different devices. For instance, MacBooks have a pixel ratio of 2 and above, some cell phones have pixel ratio of 3, and desktop monitors are usually at a ratio of 1. This can be avoided by not using `setPixelRatio`, or if you use it, you'll have to use a multiplication:

```
const s = 5;
points.size = s * window.devicePixelRatio;
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that <strike>sprites</strike> `THREE.Points` are sized in pixels, whereas meshes are sized in world units. So sometimes when you shrink your browser window vertically, the <strike>sprite</strike> `Point` size will remain the same, but the meshes will scale down to fit in the viewport. This means that a 5px <strike>sprite</strike> `Point` will take up more real-estate in a small window than it would in a large monitor. If this is the problem, make sure you use the `window.innerHeight` value when calculating <strike>sprite</strike> `Point` size.

Comment: When you disable sizeAttenuation, i.e. set sizeAttenuation to false, then size is not in pixels. It works like that when sizeAttenuation is set to true, then the size can be set in pixels, like it is in the example on threejs (https://threejs.org/examples/?q=sprites#webgl_sprites) but then are the sprites affected by distance from camera.
But when sizeAttenuation is set to false, the base sprite size looks like to cover all the screen, so you need to scale it down a lot, with scale ration around 0.05 and so on.

Comment: @JanZámečník You're absolutely right. I'm sorry, I mistakenly thought we were talking about a [`THREE.Points`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Points) object. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like a way to go. Just when I implemented it, i run into another problems. I created a new issue, as you answered this specific one. Could you take a look at the new one please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59964531/three-points-image-sprites-have-transparency-wrong-and-raycasting-is-not-consist

Comment: Hey, in your last paragraph you are writing that THREE.Points will not scale when resizing the browser vertically. Thats the behavior im looking for right now, but when testing it or viewing the threejs examples, the Points are also scaling down. Is there anything im missing?